# SQL pattern matching

Tags: sql, oracle, matching

I have a question related to SQL.

I want to match two fields for similarities and return a percentage on how similar it is.

For example if I have a field called doc, which contains the following

```
This is my first assignment in SQL
```

and in another field I have something like

```
My first assignment in SQL
```

I want to know how I can check the similarities between the two and return by how much percent.

I did some research and wanted a second opinion plus I never asked for source code. Ive looked at Soundex(), Difference(), Fuzzy string matching using Levenshtein distance algorithm.

Comment: Tip: Look into `hamming distance` and similar string similarity algorithms

Comment: I did some research and wanted a second opinion plus I never asked for source code. Ive looked at Soundex(), Difference(),
Fuzzy string matching using Levenshtein distance algorithm. Thanks for the tip nevertheless

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say what version of Oracle you are using. This example is based on 11g version.
You can use `edit_distance` function of [utl_match](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_match.htm#CBHBICDE) package to determine how many characters you need to change in order to turn one string to another. [greatest](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions069.htm#i77473) function returns the greatest value in the list of passed in parameters. Here is an example:

```
-- sample of data 
with t1(col1, col2) as(
  select 'This is my first assignment in SQL', 'My first assignment in SQL ' from dual
)
-- the query
select trunc(((greatest(length(col1), length(col2)) -  
              (utl_match.edit_distance(col2, col1))) * 100) / 
             greatest(length(col1), length(col2)), 2) as "%"
  from t1
```

result:

```
         %
----------
     70.58
```

**Addendum**

As @jonearles correctly pointed out, it is much simpler to use `edit_distance_similarity` function of `utl_match` package.

```
 with t1(col1, col2) as(
     select 'This is my first assignment in SQL', 'My first assignment in SQL ' from dual
  )
  select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(col1, col2) as "%"
    from t1
   ;
```

Result:

```
         %
----------
        71
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using Oracle 11G. I wasnt expecting any code so Thanks!

Comment: +1 You can probably simplify this with `utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(col1, col2)`.